# I tried writing this code for IRR and I'm getting really large number

Tags: python

Cash Flows are:

```
cashflows = [-500, 100, 250, 300, 100]           
r = 0.05 


def IRR(cashflows, interations=100):
        rate = 0.05
        investment = cashflows[0]
        for i in range (1 ,interations+1):
            rate*=(1-npv(r, cashflows)/investment)
        return rate
```

And the code for `npv()`:

```
    def npv(r, cashflows):

        total = 0.0  

        for i, cashflow in enumerate(cashflows, start=1):  
            total += cashflow / ((1 + r) ** i)  
        return total
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi so my question is what is wring with my code that the IRR is so large it should be according to excel 0.18 or 18% not 29389878612.149174

Comment: Your rate is being continuously compounded by multiplying itself by `(1-npv(r, cashflows)/investment)` which doesn't change. That value is about 1.3113 so you are multiplying the rate by 1.3113 on each iteration through your loop

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you're asking, let me point you in a direction that might help. [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) has a great little tool for calculating the internal rate of return for cashflows. See below:

```
import numpy as np
cashflows = [-500, 100, 250, 300, 100]
irr = np.irr(cashflows)
```

**Edited:**

Your IRR function needs adjusting. You should be passing the adjusted rate into your npv formula every time whereas you are just passing a constant rate (r = 0.05). See below:

```
def IRR(cashflows, interations=100):
        rate = 0.05
        investment = cashflows[0]
        for i in range (1 ,interations+1):
            rate*=(1-npv(rate, cashflows)/investment)
        return rate
```